# change the color of text on mouseover in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am very new to JS. My requirement is very simple, to change the color of Text on Mouse Over. 
I have created 2 JS functions : 1st for MouseOver and 2nd for MouseOut.
Can I do it in one single JS function.
I have other Text also.

### JavaScript

```js
function highlightBG(element) {  
    document.getElementById('element').className='AttachOnMouseOverText';   
}
function highlightOutBG(element){
    document.getElementById('element').className='AttachOnMouseOutText';
}
```

### HTML code :

```html
<td align="center" id="element">
    <img name="folder" onMouseOver="highlightBG();return true;" onMouseOut="highlightOutBG();return true;">
    <br>Add Folder
</td>
```

Comment: You can do things like that with javascript. But you should be looking into CSS (as you tagged it) you can use an elements parent and the `:hover` selector to change appearance. You will also don't need a `mouseOutText` class, since the `:hover` status will be removed as soon as you leave the certain element.

Comment: Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/5NA9q/ (don't use tables for lists as i did here, i followed your code.)

Comment: Yeah right..but what about combining the two functions into a single one?
The CSS classess surely solves my purpose,but I was thinking that we could perhaps do away with writing two jscript for each mouseover/mouseout event. Instead, we should call one single jscript function where we can pass parameters like out/over and id to set the style of the Text. Secondly, 'Add Folder' is not the only Text, but i have few more Texts in <td>'s which should also have the same effect

Comment: I mean, lets see my JS code :
function highlightBG(element) {    
 document.getElementById('element').className='AttachOnMouseOverText';
}
function highlightOutBG(element1){
 document.getElementById('element1').className='AttachOnMouseOutText';
}

Here istead of having two JS functions i want to use single JS and may be pass parameters to it

Answer (score 2):

You can find here the answer using pure-js as you asked :

HTML :

```
<div id="element" class="AttachOnMouseOutText" onMouseOver="highlightBG();return true;" onMouseOut="highlightOutBG();return true;">Hidden text</div>
```

CSS :

```
.AttachOnMouseOverText {
    color: white;
}

.AttachOnMouseOutText {
    color: black;
}
```

Javascript :

```
function highlightBG() {  
    document.getElementById('element').className='AttachOnMouseOverText';   
}
function highlightOutBG(){
    document.getElementById('element').className='AttachOnMouseOutText';
}
```

You can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EwAm4/) an example using CSS `:hover` state.

**EDIT**

If you want a single function to handle this, try someting like :

```
function highlightBG(elementName, isIn) {
    if (isIn)
        document.getElementById(elementName).className = 'AttachOnMouseOverText';
    else
        document.getElementById(elementName).className = 'AttachOnMouseOutText';
}
```

Comment: The thing is Client want everything to be in JS and not in JQuery. The CSS classess surely solves my purpose,but I was thinking that we could perhaps do away with writing two jscript for each mouseover/mouseout event. Instead, we should call one single jscript function where we can pass parameters like out/over and id to set the style of the Text. Secondly, 'Add Folder' is not the only Text, but i have few more Texts in <td>'s which should also have the same effect.

Comment: I don't use jQuery in my example. With what I show to you, I set the text color to the div, so all nested elements will be affected.

Comment: This is the code currently : 
function highlightBG(element) {    
 document.getElementById('element').className='AttachOnMouseOverText';
 
}
function highlightOutBG(element1){
 document.getElementById('element1').className='AttachOnMouseOutText';
} 
CSS : .AttachOnMouseOverText{
  color: blue;  
  font-size: 9px;
  text-align: center;
 }
 .AttachOnMouseOutText{
  color: black;  
  font-size: 9px;
  text-align: center;
 }

Comment: HTML: <td align="center" id="element">
    <img name="folder" onMouseOver="highlightBG();return true;" onMouseOut="highlightOutBG();return true;">
    <br>Add Folder 
</td>

 <td align="center" id="element">
    <img name="folder" onMouseOver="highlightBG();return true;" onMouseOut="highlightOutBG();return true;">
    <br>Add URL
</td>

Comment: any suggestions how to combine two JS into single one?

Answer (score 1):

this is simple by using css:

```
selector:hover
{
  color:red;
}
```

And you can also use jquery for this

```
$("selector").on( "mouseover", function() {
  $( this ).css( "color", "red" );
});
```

Comment: OP doesn't use jQuery

Comment: I don't understand why people always reference jQuery. The TS didn't asked for it, it's not advisable to include a library to achieve a simple hover effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the hover change on a link then definitely use a :hover in CSS, it will be the most efficient way.

However if you are looking to add it to a non-link element it can cause issues in IE7 and 8. Have a look at [Google Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering), in particular the section about :hover.
If that is the case then JS is a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to use jquery to do what you want, if you are using javascript you might just as well make use of jquery. Create a css class to represent the color you want to change the text to, for example

```
.green{
    color: green;
}
```

Change your HTML to

```
<td align="center" id="element">
    <img name="folder" />
    <br>Add Folder
</td>
```

And add some jquery to add your css class when you move your mouse over 'element', for example

```
$("#element").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("green");
});
```

If you want to change the color back when the mouse leaves the area, you can just remove the class again. For example

```
$( "#element" ).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("green");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the HTML (with an inline ID of "practice"):

```
<h1 id="practice">Hello!</h1>
```

Here is the vanilla JavaScript (using a generic function and a callback):

```
document.getElementById("practice").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  document.getElementById("practice").style.color = "pink";
});
document.getElementById("practice").addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  document.getElementById("practice").style.color = "yellow";
});
```

Mousing over changes the HTML text to yellow; removing the mouse from the area returns the HTML text to black.